# URL issue using multiple ids pk1 and pk2

Tags: django, django-urls

My url is not working I am getting an error :

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /website/project/172/
Could not parse the remainder: '=' from '='
```

Here is my url link :

```
<span class="fa fa-id-card-o" aria-hidden="true"><a href="{% url 'website:EmployeDetails' pk1 = project.id pk2 = member.id %}"> Show Results</a>
```

I guess it is coming from the pk1 = project.id pk2 = member.id but I dont know how to fomulate ir 
urs pattern:

```
url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='ProjectDetails'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/$',views.EmployeeDetailView.as_view(), name='EmployeDetails'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/api/chart/data/$',views.EmployeeChartData.as_view(), name='employeechartdata'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/api/chart/data/$', views.ChartData.as_view(), name='chartdata'),
```

views.py:

```
class EmployeeDetailView(generic.DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = MyUser
    template_name = 'Employee_Details.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(MyUser, pk=self.kwargs['pk2'], members__project=self.kwargs['pk1'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        employee_name = MyUser.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk2'])
        team_list = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
        team_list_pop = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all().exclude(id=self.kwargs['pk2'])
        context={
            'employee_name' : employee_name,
            'team_list' : team_list,
            'team_list_pop' : team_list_pop
        }
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces before and after the `=` signs.